# A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.8 pixels on the bottom. The relevant error-causing widget was Column

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Getting An error (**overflowed by 4.8 pixels on the bottom**). I was creating an **emailAuthSheet** with **showModalBottomSheet** while debugging the app it shows the error of overflowed. Can u please guide me...And **If Possible can you please also guide me on how to make it responsive for all devices as per their device screen size**

The following code is below:

```
emailAuthSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
              child: 
              Column(
                children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150.0),
                  child: Divider(
                    thickness: 4.0,
                    color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Provider.of<LandingService>(context,listen: false).passwordLessSignIn(context),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                        color: constantColors.blueColor,
                        child: Text(
                          'Log in',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {}),
                    MaterialButton(
                        color: constantColors.redColor,
                        child: Text(
                          'Sign in',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {})
                  ],
                ),
              ]),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: constantColors.blueGreyColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(15.0))));
        });
}
```

**Below is the pic of the flutter app and error**[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `container` with `singleChildScrollView`

```
emailAuthSheet(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              child:
              Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150.0),
                      child: Divider(
                        thickness: 4.0,
                        color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Provider.of<LandingService>(context,listen: false).passwordLessSignIn(context),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        MaterialButton(
                            color: constantColors.blueColor,
                            child: Text(
                              'Log in',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {}),
                        MaterialButton(
                            color: constantColors.redColor,
                            child: Text(
                              'Sign in',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {})
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: constantColors.blueGreyColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(15.0)))),
        );
      });
}
```

Comment: i'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'isScrollControlled' parameter true to showModalBottomSheet.
And changed Column widget to Wrap widget.
(I removed some defines and widget because of leak of data)

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  emailAuthSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return Container(
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150.0),
                child: Divider(
                  thickness: 4.0,
                ),
              ),
              Container(height: 450, color: Colors.blue[100]),
              // Provider.of<LandingService>(context,listen: false).passwordLessSignIn(context),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  MaterialButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Log in',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {}),
                  MaterialButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign in',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {})
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          emailAuthSheet(context);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: sir but how to make the full flutter app responsive so that it adjust to all screen size

Comment: As you see my code, there is no container's height and width in this bottom sheet. For all layout you need to use MediaQuery or other package. ex. ScreenUtil, Sizer.  
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil https://pub.dev/packages/sizer